# Reactjs import from another repo

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Reactjs, I have two repos and one is importing components from the other. Trying to import modules, I get this error:

Module parse failed: [path] Unexpected token (22:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. 
| render(){
|    ...
| }

Here's my webpack.config.js module loaders:

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
  },
]
```

},

What am I missing here? 
The two repos work great on their own, the minute I try to load one from the other, that's the error I get.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out to add a couple of lines in that configuration:

```
 module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: /node_modules\/my-react-comps-styleguide/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }
]
```

},

notice what i added there to include from the node_modules. 
Now it works good.

I also noticed one can add this too:

```
include: [
     path.join(process.cwd(),'src'),
     path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/[modulename]')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not missing `babel-loader`'s `test` property?

In a ReactJS application is usually set like:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    // Further config
}
```

Comment: yes, I was looking to what extra configuration needed for that part. Just figured it out. Check my answer.. Thanks